# Python Pandas - Return default value when match not found

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am comparing 2 CSV files with pandas python and all is working correctly.  It is matching on the **employee_id** column and outputting the results to a csv file

```
    df1 = pd.read_csv('input1.csv', sep=',\s+', delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8")
    df2 = pd.read_csv('input2.csv', sep=',\s,', delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8")
    df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='employee_id', how='right')
    df3.to_csv('output.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

When it does not find a match it returns a blank result, I would like it to instead return **not_found**

Is this possible with Pandas or should I do some processing afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) if no `NaN` in `df1`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'employee_id':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (df1)
   B  C  employee_id
0  4  7            1
1  5  8            2
2  6  9            3

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'employee_id':[1,4,6],
                   'D':[4,5,6],
                   'E':[7,8,9]})

print (df2)
   D  E  employee_id
0  4  7            1
1  5  8            4
2  6  9            6

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='employee_id', how='right')
df3[df1.columns] = df3[df1.columns].fillna('not_found')
print (df3)
           B          C  employee_id  D  E
0          4          7            1  4  7
1  not_found  not_found            4  5  8
2  not_found  not_found            6  6  9
```

But if `NaN` in `df1` is necessary create mask for identify missing values from `right` join - with parameter `indicator=True` in [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) or with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and negate mask by `~`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'employee_id':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[np.nan,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (df1)
     B  C  employee_id
0  NaN  7            1
1  5.0  8            2
2  6.0  9            3

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='employee_id', how='right', indicator=True)
mask = df3['_merge'] == 'right_only'
df3.loc[mask, df1.columns.difference(['employee_id'])] = 
df3.loc[mask,df1.columns.difference(['employee_id'])].fillna('not_found')

df3 = df3.drop('_merge', axis=1)
print (df3)
           B          C  employee_id  D  E
0        NaN          7            1  4  7
1  not_found  not_found            4  5  8
2  not_found  not_found            6  6  9
```

---

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='employee_id', how='right')
mask = ~df2['employee_id'].isin(df1['employee_id'])

df3.loc[mask, df1.columns.difference(['employee_id'])] = \
df3.loc[mask,df1.columns.difference(['employee_id'])].fillna('not_found')

print (df3)
           B          C  employee_id  D  E
0        NaN          7            1  4  7
1  not_found  not_found            4  5  8
2  not_found  not_found            6  6  9
```

Comment: Thank you very much, they are great examples.  Saves me having to process the file afterwards

Comment: Glad can help you ;) Nice day!